# add multi resource to c++ and extract them to temp folder to use

Tags: c++, resources

I want to add some resource file (binary file and exe) to my **c++** program

after add resource im plan to build a exe from my c++ program to use in windows

when exe run, it extract resource  file to temp folder and use them...

after that when exe closed delete temp folder

how can i do that?
If the question doesn't seem right, I'm sorry because I just started working with c ++